# Read receipts for emails sent via SQL Server Database Mail?

Tags: sql-server, email, email-server

We use SQL Server Database Mail to send emails from one of our apps. It calls the sp_send_dbmail stored procedure. I've been asked to see if there is a way to add a read receipt to emails sent this way.

The sp doesn't seem to have this option. And the Database Mail Configuration doesn't seem to have settings for it either. So, I'm assuming it's not possible. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Database Mail doesn't have any mechanism for requesting receipts.  You'd either have to put some kind of hack in place, like an smtp relay that SQL forwards to that could add one on the fly, or use a different mail library to send your messages.

Answer (score 0):

Who's going to read the receipt? The SQL server?

Comment: Um, SQL sends the message as someone else (in the From field) so that person would get the receipt....

Comment: Why the down vote? The OP didn't give any specifics about what he ultimately wanted to accomplish by setting up a Read Receipt and I asked a legitimate question.

Comment: I'm not the one who down voted. But I'm guessing they wanted you to ask clarifying questions in comments instead.

Comment: The question was clear, the OP wants to know if it's possible to request read receipts via database mail.  Without further clarification your answer could easily be taken as sarcasm, and really belongs as a comment to the question anyway.

Comment: Point taken, but is a down vote really warranted? Your comment to my comment could be perceived as sarcasm, so do you get a down vote as well? I'm not trying to be pithy, but it seems that down votes can be arbitrary at times, especially since my question was well meaning, albeit short on clarification.